# Why is the fundamental group of the circle so non-trivial?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I've recently learned that the fundamental group of the circle is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. I'm having a hard time picturing loops in $S^1$; can you give some intuition for why that group has such a rich structure?

Comment: Well, not *so* rich. And isn't going around a circle a loop itself?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#Low-dimensional_examples has some pictures.

Comment: Out of curiosity: If someone had come to you and asked, "What is the fundamental group of the circle?", what would have been your reply (or your suspicion)?

Comment: To answer the question in the subject line: Because a circle has a one dimensional  hole, and you can go around it infinitely many times..

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang well I was trying to think if there were loops in the circle that don't cover the circle; would these not be continuous? Also I'm trying to understand whether, if $h \in \pi_{1}(S^1)* $then $[h] = [-h]$

Comment: @Chappers thanks for the link

Comment: Take a large rubber band. And a newspaper. if you put the rubber band loosely around the paper, that's the standard loop. If you cross and twist and wrap the band once, that's a double loop. If you take the ``x" you just formed and wrap around the paper again, that's a four loop. If instead of grabbing the "x" you grabbed a single strand of plastic and wrapped it around (forming two distinct "x"s) that would be a three loop. ad infinitum. if you care about the negative numbers, think of adding an orientation to the rubber band.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think one thing that may be confusing you is that you are envisioning a "loop" in a space as a circle sitting inside the space.  This picture is incorrect: a loop is a map from a circle to your space, but this map does not need to be injective!  So your vision of a loop should be dynamic: it is a a path that you can trace in the space which may cross or repeat itself, not just a fixed subset of the space.

With this picture, the loops in $S^1$ corresponding to the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ are quite simple.  Namely, a nonnegative integer $n$ corresponds to the path that goes all the way around the circle $n$ times counterclockwise.  Negative integers are similar, except you go around clockwise instead.  So even though a circle has only one "loop" to go around, a path can traverse that loop multiple times (and can go either forward or backwards), and that's how you end up with an entire $\mathbb{Z}$ in the fundamental group.

Comment: If m and n are distinct integers, what would make a loop going around the circle n times different from one going around the circle m times? Can we not deform one into the other?

Comment: How exactly would you deform one into the other?

Comment: I saw an example where a loop that first going around the circle twice anti-clockwise, then once more clockwise being deformed to a loop going around the circle just once clockwise. Why can't the same procedure be applied here?

Comment: @ensbana: Well, what is "the same procedure"?  The deformation in that example uses the fact that some of the parts of the loop are going in opposite directions around the circle.

Comment: Say we take $m =1$ and $n= -1$, and instead of loops I will just work with paths. Let $f$ be a path from $a$ to $b$ and $f^{-1}$ the inverse path. How do I show that there's no homotopies between $f$ and $f^{-1}$?

Comment: That's a nontrivial theorem which is usually proved using covering spaces.  Briefly, you lift these paths to the covering space $\mathbb{R}$ of $S^1$ and find they have different endpoints so they cannot be homotopic (rel their endpoints).

Answer (score 2):

Imagine any loop $\gamma$  in the punctured plane $\dot{\mathbb R}^2$. The normalization map
$$\nu:\quad (x,y)\mapsto{1\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(x,y)$$
converts $\gamma$ into the loop $\gamma':=\nu\circ\gamma$ on $S^1$. The given $\gamma$ has a winding number
$$N(\gamma,0)={1\over2\pi}\int_\gamma\nabla{\rm arg}({\bf z})\cdot d{\bf z}\qquad\left(={1\over 2\pi i}\int_\gamma{dz\over z}\right)$$
with respect to the origin, and this is also the winding number (or the degree) of $\gamma'\subset S^1$.

It is one of the most basic and all important facts of geometry and analysis that this degree characterizes $\gamma$, resp. $\gamma'$, up to homotopy – in other terms: that the fundamental group of $S^1$ is cyclic.

Comment: See also this mathoverflow discussion https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one/46808#46808